# How to use jboss portlet bridge or liferay bridge?

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, liferay-7, portletbridge

I got a requirement where I need to display an other teams jsp page into my application (vue.js/jsp application) in a iframe without using company network. Their url only works in company network. Some team achieved it long back via jboss portlet bridge technology. have no idea it works? Not much material available online as well. I heard liferay can be used but I have no idea about it too. Can some one please help. Thanks

Comment: 1990s technology.  Who would go back to that?

Comment: yeah. But not sure what latest tech can help to achieve it?

Comment: This needs a lot of clarity: You mention (and tag) Liferay, but the direction of what's included where is absolutely unclear to me. Current Liferay versions make it trivial to embed your own vue application, so you can do whatever you want in that vue app, without relying on server-side integrations. Please see [ask] and edit your question to contain a [mcve]